# Adding an onclick event to every a tag with a certain id

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

My javascript is very rusty but I'd like to have a global function for my website that adds an onclick event for every a tag with a certain id attached to it. So throughout my website I have various  tags with id's myLink1, myLink2, myLink3 etc.

I'd like to make a function on my website so

if  tag has id which includes "myLink", then add onclick=function() to that tag. It would be the same function() for each myLink regardless whether it's myLink1, myLink2 etc

Don't know if that's even possible.

Comment: yes, it's possible, but easier if you also add a single common class to those tags

Comment: also ... `various tags` ... you mean they are not all one type of tag, i.e. not all `input` or all `div` etc, just various different tags?

Comment: to get you going, `document.querySelectorAll('[id^=myLink]')` will find any element whose id begins with `myLink`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem you can use this.

but maybe as  @Jaromanda X said adding classes can make this easier

```
function test() {
    alert( "1234" );
}

window.onload = function() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll( '[id^=myLink]' );
    for( i=0; i<links.length; i++ ) {
        links[i].setAttribute( "onclick", "test()" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I dont know the HTML code and tried to help using what was told

Comment: Thanks for your responses

So it would be like

function test(){
    functioniwanttorunonclick();
}

window.onload = function(){
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for(i=0; i<links.length; i++){
    links[i].setAttribute("onclick", "test()");
  }
}

Classes would probably be better but at the moment they are identified by id=mylink1, mylink2 etc.

On the above code, how would I get it to identify all the mylinks, regardless of the following number

Like identify all a tags with the id mylink*, in order to add the onclick attribute

Comment: Yes. And if you want to identify by id instead of document.getElementsByTagName("a"); you can use document.querySelectorAll('[id^=myLink]') as @Jaromanda X said

Comment: Thanks again

So like

`function test(){
    functioniwanttorunonclick();
}

window.onload = function(){
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=myLink]');
  for(i=0; i<links.length; i++){
    links[i].setAttribute("onclick", "test()");
  }
}`

Comment: If you already have the function you can do like this links[i].setAttribute("onclick", "functioniwanttorunonclick()");

Comment: In your jsfiddle case if you want to write this you have to change the load type on javascript part and make a change to this links[i].setAttribute("onclick", "alert('1234')");